# Access Period Sort

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to pull records from a specific period into a form.  I need to be able to pull the information from a date field within a table to put into the form.  I need it to prompt for a date range and that date range show in the form/report.  I am having trouble making this work.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) I don't understand what is the question? We need more context to be able to help you. What have you tried so far, how has it failed? Post code and whatever else is needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of selecting a date range using parameters that you specify. It will prompt you to enter a start and end date
AND it will return the dates you selected as fields in the query.
You can use the start/end fields in your form/report.

```
SELECT [Table1].*, [StartDate] AS MyStart, [EndDate] AS MyEnd
FROM Table1
WHERE ((([Table1].DateAdded) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate]));
```

Comment: This is great but where do I put this?  It does not look like the macro editor will add this language.  Am I off track?

Comment: Let's assume you are dealing with a Form. If you set the recordsource of the form to SQL similar to what I have shown, then open in Form View, you will be prompted to enter two dates. Your Form can reference fields 'MyEnd' and 'MyStart' so they appear on your form. So, does this satisfy your original question: (1) pull records from a specific period? YES; (2) from a date field within a table? YES; (3) prompt for a date range? YES; (4) show that date range in the form? YES.. The TITLE of your question mentions SORT... either remove or clarify. What level of expertise do you have with Access?